# Создание матрицы объектов

Tags: c++, классы, матрицы

Пытаюсь создать класс поля заполненного объектами. Объясните пожалуйста в чём ошибка.

```
class Object {
public:
    char object;
    Object(char obj) :object(obj) {};
    Object() :object('X') {};
};
class Map
{
    Map(int& x, int& y) {
        int count_object = 0;
        int width = 2 * x + 3;
        int height = y + 2;
  
        Object* line = new Object(); // Обявление края карты 
        Object* o = new Object(' '); // Обявление пустоты внутри карты
        Object** field = new Object  *[height];

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            field[i] = new Object[width];
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                if ((i == 0 && i == height - 1 && j == 0 || j == width - 1) && (j % 2 == 0))
                {
                    field[i][j] = line; // Проблема здесь
                }
                else
                {
                    field[i][j] = o;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы присваиваете указатель, а не объект:

```
Object** field
```

значит, `field[i][j]` имеет тип `Object&`. А `line` и `o` у вас указатели.

Чтоб *просто скомпилировалось*, достаточно

```
field[i][j] = *line;
```

Но будет ли это верно работать — не уверен, как минимум, имеется утечка памяти. Специально код не смотрел.

Вы не из java/c# на C++ переходите?